# Shares and printers on a server are not accessible for one workstation

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-7, windows-server-2012, file-sharing

The PC in question is running Windows 7 and the server is Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Both machines can ping each other by IP and Name.

I've tried flushing the DNS cache, removing the pc from the domain and re-adding it(Which caused more problems and needed a system restore to get back on the domain!).

Any help with this will be greatly awarded with smilies!!! :-)

Comment: Define "not accessible". What are you actually seeing on the screen of the client computer? Do local printer(s) on that machine work? Is the "Print Spooler" service running on that machine?

Comment: An error message displays saying that the network path was not found. There are no local printers on-site and I have verified that the print spooler is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, there are several things that it could be, but...

- Check your antivirus logs on both machines.
- Check any other security/firewall software on both machines.
- Make sure the workstation service is running and the client for microsoft networks is installed in the network adapter's properties.
- [This guy](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/04/UNC-Drive-Mapping-Failures-Network-name-cannot-be-found) says he resolved a similar issue by editing the registry to change the key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order` to `LanmanWorkstation,RDPNP,webclient` on the advice of [a technet forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4d40dd77-3c1f-4c94-9688-a8a710870a86/windows-2008-r2-server-unable-to-browse-unc-shares?forum=winserverPN).

Hopefully one of those will help you out.

Comment: Thanks Katherine. It turns out the problem was with the firewall. Really appreciate the help and as promised here are some smilies :-) :-) :-) :-)